# How can I sort in ascending order on an inner field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a list of entries and I would like to sort them by a specific field.
The command I'm am running is

```
db.getSiblingDB("stocks").getCollection("fundamental").find({},{"company_overview.Symbol" : 1,"company_overview.EVToEBITDA" : 1}).sort( { "company_overview.EVToEBITDA":-1 } ).limit(100)
```

and it works fine (except that the sort is non numeric which is to be expected as the field is a string)

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645add93605b5e734334cf"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALKS", "EVToEBITDA" : "97.4702" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645bc593605b5e7343358e"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALSN", "EVToEBITDA" : "9.9669" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645df793605b5e73433aab"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AMG", "EVToEBITDA" : "9.8186" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064595893605b5e7343314a"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AKU", "EVToEBITDA" : "9.1503" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064565c93605b5e73432bd6"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AHCO", "EVToEBITDA" : "88.4891" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064567d93605b5e73432c13"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AHPI", "EVToEBITDA" : "87.7453" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645a7093605b5e73433402"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALGN", "EVToEBITDA" : "83.1227" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60644f6493605b5e73432526"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ADSK", "EVToEBITDA" : "80.1307" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60644f7393605b5e73432533"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ADT", "EVToEBITDA" : "8.6308" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064501293605b5e734325b7"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AE", "EVToEBITDA" : "8.3004" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60644bc693605b5e7343223f"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ACMR", "EVToEBITDA" : "75.184" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60644f8393605b5e7343253f"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ADTN", "EVToEBITDA" : "74.6548" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645a6193605b5e734333d0"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALGM", "EVToEBITDA" : "70.0582" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606454be93605b5e73432a15"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AGI", "EVToEBITDA" : "7.5756" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60645bb593605b5e73433581"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALSK", "EVToEBITDA" : "7.2837" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064465093605b5e73431db6"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AA", "EVToEBITDA" : "7.2506" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("60644d7793605b5e73432392"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ACY", "EVToEBITDA" : "65.7269" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606455e993605b5e73432b78"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AGYS", "EVToEBITDA" : "62.342" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606459f493605b5e734332ad"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "ALCO", "EVToEBITDA" : "6.8106" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064547093605b5e73432966"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AGFS", "EVToEBITDA" : "6.7519" } ] }
```

However if i change the sorting order to ascending and I run:

```
db.getSiblingDB("stocks").getCollection("fundamental").find({},{"company_overview.Symbol" : 1,"company_overview.EVToEBITDA" : 1}).sort( { "company_overview.EVToEBITDA":1 } ).limit(100)
```

I get the entries in their _id order:

```
Shell>db.getSiblingDB("stocks").getCollection("fundamental").find({},{"company_overview.Symbol" : 1,"company_overview.EVToEBITDA" : 1}).sort( { "company_overview.EVToEBITDA":1 } ).limit(100)
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606442e493605b5e73431b78"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAPL", "EVToEBITDA" : "23.4217" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064464193605b5e73431daa"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "A", "EVToEBITDA" : "29.9561" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064465093605b5e73431db6"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AA", "EVToEBITDA" : "7.2506" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064472893605b5e73431e48"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAC", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064473793605b5e73431e54"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AACG", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064474793605b5e73431e63"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AACQ", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064475693605b5e73431e70"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AACQU", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064476693605b5e73431ea2"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AACQW", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064478493605b5e73431eb9"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAIC", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064479493605b5e73431ec6"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAL", "EVToEBITDA" : "179.8268" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447a393605b5e73431ed2"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAMC", "EVToEBITDA" : "2.5665" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447b393605b5e73431edf"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAME", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447c393605b5e73431eeb"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAN", "EVToEBITDA" : "5.9561" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447d293605b5e73431ef8"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAOI", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447e193605b5e73431f06"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAON", "EVToEBITDA" : "29.405" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("606447f193605b5e73431f16"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAP", "EVToEBITDA" : "15.2814" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064481293605b5e73431f2e"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAT", "EVToEBITDA" : "16.8257" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064482293605b5e73431f3b"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAU", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064483293605b5e73431f4a"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AAWW", "EVToEBITDA" : "3.8657" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6064485193605b5e73431f61"), "company_overview" : [ { "Symbol" : "AB", "EVToEBITDA" : "0" } ] }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the company_overview field is in fact an array and sorting should be done using

```
.sort( { "company_overview.0.EVToEBITDA":1 } )
```

I still don't know why it works when sorting descending without the ".0" part because if it was consistent and it didn't work perhaps I would have noticed the fact that company_overview is a array way earlier.